# how to get last working day from date if selected date is monday in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

i want to make a function in oracle database. in witch i want to get 1 day previous date from selected date, if selected date is "Monday" then i want to select date of "Friday" as previous date as it is last working day of week.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried using so that you can get help with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PREVIOUS_WORKING_DAY(pDate IN DATE)
  RETURN DATE
IS
  strDay_of_week  VARCHAR2(50);
  dtPrev          DATE;
BEGIN
  strDay_of_week := TRIM(TO_CHAR(pDate, 'DAY'));

  CASE strDay_of_week
    WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN
      dtPrev := TRUNC(pDate) - INTERVAL '3' DAY;
    WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN
      dtPrev := TRUNC(pDate) - INTERVAL '2' DAY;
    ELSE
      dtPrev := TRUNC(pDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END CASE;

  RETURN dtPrev;
END PREVIOUS_WORKING_DAY;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Trim the Value `strDay_of_week` gives the exact result

Comment: @hiFI - I hadn't realized that the string returned by TO_CHAR with the 'DAY' format had blanks trailing it. You're absolutely correct. Thank you. Unfortunately I can't go back and approve the edit you made, although I would if I could. [This discussion on Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251337/is-there-a-way-for-an-author-to-accept-improve-a-suggested-edit-after-its-been) is relevant, and I've posted a comment to it indicating I think it's high time to have this feature implemented. In any case, many thanks for pointing this out.